# Why my XamarinMediaManager can't play HLS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am about to play HLS on the android device by Xamarin.Forms(5.0.0.2012).

I referenced the XamarinMediaManager Nuget Package(1.0.8)

And the android version is 10.0(Q).

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                              xmlns:mm="clr-namespace:MediaManager.Forms;assembly=MediaManager.Forms"
             x:Class="Test.Pages.RootPage" NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False" >
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <mm:VideoView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Source="http://live4.tdm.com.mo/ch1/_definst_/ch1.live/playlist.m3u8" ShowControls="False" x:Name="Player" AutoPlay="True" />
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

And here is the code in MainActivity of the android project:

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using MediaManager;

namespace Test.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "Test", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize )]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;            
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);            
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);            
            CrossMediaManager.Current.Init(this);
            LoadApplication(new App());            
        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

After the program ran, it always can't play anything.
[image]

What's wrong with my code? Thank you.

Comment: I tested with the same version. It works on Androiod 10.0. Check the screenshot. https://imgur.com/CiIfmJT Have you check your network or test on other devices?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT The URL you were playing is the APPLE HLS Stream(All of us play it well also) while we are discussing another Stream: live4.tdm.com.mo/ch1/_definst_/ch1.live/playlist.m3u8

Comment: I rechecked the link. This link `http://live4.tdm.com.mo/ch1/_definst_/ch1.live/playlist.m3u8` seems wrong. It shows something on Android 8.0. https://imgur.com/zgU00lk But on Android 10.0, shows a blank screen like you.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT If I play the URL with a windows player(such as potplayer), it plays well. It seems it is some bug of android, right?

Comment: Check the code in the blog. ExoPlayer supports high-performance features like DASH and HLS streaming that are not available in MediaPlayer.  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/play-audio-and-video-with-the-mediamanager-plugin-for-xamarin/#android-exoplayer

Answer (score 0):

In code behind, write following code :

var item = await CrossMediaManager.Current.Extractor.CreateMediaItem("https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/streaming/examples/bipbop_16x9/bipbop_16x9_variant.m3u8");
item.MediaType = MediaType.Hls;

await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(item);

For better understanding, please go through following [HLS Video sample application](https://github.com/MridulMalviya/HTTPLiveStreaming)

Comment: I downloaded your sample project and ran it. However, it still no work.

Comment: I tried the m3u8 URL in your project by a third-party player and works well.

Comment: @MelonNG, For me it is working. Can tell me where you getting issue?

Comment: It runs without any error while only can't play the HLS video. No matter you click the play button whatever time, it still won't play anymore.

Comment: @MelonNG, this link http://live4.tdm.com.mo/ch1/_definst_/ch1.live/playlist.m3u8 is throwing following exception:-1>java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to live4.tdm.com.mo not permitted
 2>com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$HttpDataSourceException: Unable to connect. I changed in android manifest. Now code is working for https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/streaming/examples/bipbop_16x9/bipbop_16x9_variant.m3u8 . [you can check](https://github.com/MridulMalviya/HTTPLiveStreaming)

Comment: I did what you said and actually, the apple stream works well now. However, I tried some third-party players in windows(such as potplayer) to play error stream, and all play it well. I doubt whether there is some bug with the XamarinMediaManager.